# Hood of defiance for Huskar

Tags: dota

Since BKB prevents Huskar from getting damaged by his ulti when activated as Life Break deals magical damage to both Huskar and its enemy. Does Hood of defiance reduce damage dealt to Huskar as well?

Comment: @downvoter, why the downvote? It's a good clear question with a well-defined answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it works, you can use Hood  of defiance to reduce the damage inflicted to yourself with life break. However I recommand to not use this item on Huskar as his magic resistance grows as his life decrease so putting Hood on him is quite useless. Since the last big update, he no longer gains damage when his life is low so damage item to compensate seems the way to go (Armlet, Cristalys) or massive tank items (Hearth of Tarrasque, Assault Cuirrass, BKB)